# Is there a way to create nested list in XSL-Fo format ?

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'd like the output to look like this :

```
 a. Pets' names and preferences
    i. Charlie
         1. Tuna
         2. Scratching   
   ii.  Fluffy
         1. Corn
         2. Running
```

But can't find a way to do it by way of nesting `<fo:list-item>.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest `fo:list-block` inside `fo:list-item-body`.

`fo:list-item-body` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_list-item-body) can contain any of the `%block;` FOs (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#block.fo.list), and `fo:list-block` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_list-block) is one.

You'll end up with FOs nesting like:

```
fo:list-block
  fo:list-item
    fo:list-item-label
      fo:block
    fo:list-item-body
      fo:list-block
        fo:list-item
          fo:list-item-label
            fo:block
          fo:list-item-body
            fo:block
        fo:list-item
          fo:list-item-label
            fo:block
          fo:list-item-body
            fo:block
  fo:list-item
    fo:list-item-label
      fo:block
    fo:list-item-body
      fo:list-block
        fo:list-item
          fo:list-item-label
            fo:block
          fo:list-item-body
            fo:block
        fo:list-item
          fo:list-item-label
            fo:block
          fo:list-item-body
            fo:block
```

You'll need to correctly set `provisional-distance-between-starts` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#provisional-distance-between-starts) and `provisional-label-separation` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#provisional-label-separation) on each `fo:list-block` so that the list items are indented the way that you want.